# Diagonalizability, orthogonal diagonalizability of higher order tensors and their being or not being dense in some suitable topology

Tags: linear-algebra, tensor-products, tensor, tensor-powers, tensor-calculus

For our discussion, we'll assume that we're working with $\mathbb{R}^m$ only, but much or all of the following discussion should be carried over immediately to any finite dimensional inner product space.

For completeness, we'll state a few definitions, that'll be used in the questions that follow.

**1) Tensors:** We'll call **$T$ a tensor of order $k$ (or just a $k$-tensor) on $\mathbb{R}^m$** if $T:(\mathbb{R}^m)^k\to \mathbb{R}$ is a $k$-linear map.

**2) Tensor product of two $1$-linear forms on $\mathbb{R}^m:$**

Let $A, B: \mathbb{R}^m\to \mathbb{R}$ be two $1$-linear forms. Then we define their tensor product $A\otimes B$ to be the bilinear form: $A\otimes B: (v,w)\mapsto A(v)B(w).$

**3) Constructing a $k$-tensor from just one vector:** Identifying $\mathbb{R}^m$ with its dual thanks to the canonical inner product on $\mathbb{R}^m,$ we can think of any vector $v$ as a $1$-linear form, and $v\otimes v\otimes \dots \otimes v =:v^{\otimes k}$ as a $k$-linear form (i.e. a $k$-tensor).

**4) Symmetry:** We define $T$ to be **symmetric** if $T(\sigma(v_1),\dots \sigma(v_n))=T(v_1\dots v_n)$ for every permutation $\sigma.$

**5) Diagonalizability and orthogonal diagonalizability :** Let $\{v_1\dots v_m\}$ be a basis for $\mathbb{R}^m.$ We say that $T$ is **diagonalizable** if there exist $\lambda_i\in \mathbb{R}, 1\le i \le m,$ so that $T=\sum_{i=1}^{k}\lambda_iv_i^{\otimes k}.$ Furthermore, we define $T$ to be **orthogonally diagonalizable** (in short, odeco, following [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1409.6685.pdf)) if $v_i's$ form an orthonormal basis for $\mathbb{R}^m.$ Note that $T$ is odeco implies that there exists $R\in O(n), R:=[v_1\dots v_m],$ so that $T(x\dots x)=\sum_{i=1}^{m}\lambda_i(Rx)_i^k.$

P.S. The paper linked above, as well [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1210.7559.pdf) do *not* define **diagonalizability** of a tensor, although they do **orthogonally diagonalizable**. I made up the former definition just by dropping the assumption that the basis need *not* be orthonormal. Also they used the word "orthogonally decomposable" instead of "orthogonally diagonalizable."

**Here are my questions:**

1. **By the definition above, all diagonalizable tensors are symmetric** (but this is not the case for matrices, so I'm having trouble here - **did I define diagonalizability of a tensor correctly?**)
2. When $k=2,$ a tensor becomes a bilinear form, that correspond to a matrix after choosing a basis. We know, thanks to the spectral theorem, that **symmetry of a matrix is *equivalent* to orthogonal diagonalizability**. However, the papers linked above claim that there that this is not so for higher order tensors. **What's an example of a symmetric tensor that is not orthogonally diagonalizable (with proof), please?**
3. **Density(?):** What's an appropriate topology (ideally a metrizable one) on the space of $k$-tensors, and in this topology, can we approximate a symmetric tensor by a sequence of orthogonally diagonalizable tensors? If no, then how about a sequence of diagonalizable tensors?

Relevant references very highly appreciated! I'll take the liberty to add a few, as it appears that tensors have been of interest in the signal processing community more than the math community.

i) https://hal.science/hal-00561523/file/ifac94.pdf

Answer (score 3):

1. This is indeed true, and this may be the reason why the paper uses *decomposable* instead of *diagonalizable*. In the context of general tensors, it may be better to define diagonalizability as $$T = \sum_{i = 1}^n \lambda_i v_{1i} \otimes v_{2i} \otimes \dots \otimes v_{ki}$$ for some bases $v_{p1}, \dots, v_{pn}$. If the tensor is symmetric, then this notion of diagonalizability is equivalent to the symmetric version from your post (Proof for $k \geq 3$: Take a basis $u_{11}, \dots, u_{1n}$ biorthogonal to $v_{11}, \dots, v_{1n}$. Then the contraction $$T \cdot u_{1i} = v_{2i} \otimes \dots \otimes v_{ki}$$ is a rank $1$ symmetric tensor, so $v_{2i},\dots,v_{ki}$ are proportional to each other. Now do the same on any other factor to also include $v_{1i}$).
2. Consider the $W$-tensor $$W = e_0 \otimes e_0 \otimes e_1 + e_0 \otimes e_1 \otimes e_0 + e_1 \otimes e_0 \otimes e_0.$$ As in the previous point, if $W$ is diagonalizable, then there exists a basis $u_0, u_1$ such that the contraction $W \cdot u_i$ has rank $1$. But for $u = \alpha_0 e_0 + \alpha_1 e_1$ we have $$W \cdot u = \begin{bmatrix} \alpha_1 & \alpha_0 \\ \alpha_0 & 0 \end{bmatrix},$$ so the only $u$ such that $W \cdot u$ has rank $1$ is proportional to $e_1$. Contradiction. (This is a well-known proof, usually used to prove the fact that $W$ has tensor rank greater than $2$).
3. Tensor product is a finite-dimensional vector space, so there is a unique topology compatible with vector space structure, and it comes from the usual norm.
   The set of orthogonally diagonalizable tensors is, I believe, closed (if we allow $\lambda_i = 0$), because you can always define a limit of a family of orthonormal bases.
   $W$ can be approximated by diagonalizable tensors (this is usually stated as follows: border rank $\underline{R}(W) = 2$), but there are larger examples which cannot be approximated. For example, $$H = \sum_{\sigma \in S_3} e_{\sigma 1} \otimes e_{\sigma 2} \otimes e_{\sigma 3}$$ has border rank $4$, that is, not approximable by diagonalizable tensors. The tensor $H$ is a special case of a *small Coppersmith-Winograd tensor* used in matrix multiplication algorithms.

In general, tensors diagonalizable in the sense I defined in the beginning have tensor rank $n$, and tensors approximated by diagonalizable have border rank $n$. If the tensor is concise (nondegenerate in some sense), it always has border rank at least $n$, so concise tensors of border rank $n$ are called tensors of *minimal border rank*. This is a complicated class, you can look at the paper [Concise tensors of minimal border rank](https://arxiv.org/abs/2205.05713) by Jelisiejew, Landsberg and Pal, and references therein for the information on them. (UPDATE: if we are talking about real tensors, things are even more complicated. The structure tensor of $\mathbb{C}$ as an algebra over $\mathbb{R}$ has rank $2$ over $\mathbb{C}$ but not over $\mathbb{R}$)

There is also literature on orthogonal decompositions, but I'm not very familiar with it.

Comment: Many thanks Vladimir - your answer is surely helpful! This is just a quick thank you - I'll take some time to read your answer and may follow up should I have any questions! Thanks again!!